# How to use a quotation as an extraneous part of a sentence?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, punctuation

I've been trying to use a quotation as an extraneous part of the sentence and wanted to see if there is any grammar convention surrounding it.

Sample sentence:

> Her answer, “I don’t demand ‘new year, new supplies’ I am content with the things I have,” emboldens a teaching in judicious usage.

I want it to sound like:

> **Her answer**, “I don’t demand ‘new year, new supplies’ I am content with the things I have,” **emboldens a teaching in judicious usage**.

Comment: Such as (and forgive me if this is not what you seek) parentheses?

Comment: Her answer “I don’t demand ‘new year, new supplies’; I am content with the things I have” emboldens teaching in a judicious usage. It can also be an indirect narration like "Her answer that she doesn't demand new year new supplies and she is content with the things she has, emboldens teaching in a judicious usage.